# Ordenar un String con datos numéricos y guiones

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo que crear en Java un objeto company con una serie de atributos. Uno de ellos es el tamaño que me viene en String y tiene este formato

- 1-10
- 11-50
- 51-200
- 1000-5000

Al hacer una query en el repositorio para que me devuelva una lista de company ordenadas por tamaño de manera ascendente lo que hace es considerar que 1000 va antes de 11. Entiendo que al ser el segundo numero más pequeño que el segundo numero de la segunda cifra, es la lógica que sirve.

```
    @Entity (name="company")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString

``public class Company {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    private String website;
    private String name;
    @Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0)
    private Integer founded;
    private String size;
    private String locality;
    private String region;
    private String country;
    private String industry;
    @Column(name="linkedin_url")
    private String linkedinUrl;

    public Company(String id, String website, String name, Integer founded, String size, String locality, String region, String country, String industry, String linkedinUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.website = website;
        this.name = name;
        this.founded = founded;
        this.size = size;
        this.locality = locality;
        this.region = region;
        this.country = country;
        this.industry = industry;
        this.linkedinUrl = linkedinUrl;
    }

    public Company() {

    }
}

        @Query("select c from company c order by c.size")
    List<Company> findByOrderBySizeAsc();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en Español.
Si quieres modificar la query para obtener los datos ordenados, creo que es importante que digas qué motor de B.D. estás utilizando.

Comment: Hola Germán, estoy utilizando SQL pero estoy llamando desde una query en Java

Comment: ¿La query la estás lanzando desde JAVA, pero contra qué Base de Datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es ordenar por el primer tamaño del `SIZE`, lo que necesitas es obtener como elemento único ese primer tamaño.

Para ello debes:

- Primero buscar la posición del character **"-"**
- Segundo cortar la cadena para quedarte con laparte que hay entes de ese carácter.

En el caso de **SQLServer** (por ejemplo) lo prmero se hace con la función `CHARINDEX` y lo segundo con la función `SUBSTRING`. En tu caso no comentas qué Gestor de B.D. utilizas, pero deberías buscar las equivalentes.

Una consulta como esta:

```
select c.*, CHARINDEX('-', c.size) as POS, RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.size, 0, CHARINDEX('-', c.size))) SIZE1 
from company c
```

Te debería devolcver la posición del **"-"**, y la cadena que hay antes de él. Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de ahí, es sencillo obtener la ordenación aghora, simplemente debes utilizar el campo con el "nuevo" valor `SIZE1`  en lugar del campo `SIZE`.

```
Select DATA.*  from 
(
select c.id, RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.size, 0, CHARINDEX('-', c.size))) SIZE1 from company c 
) DATA
ORDER BY CAST(DATA.SIZE1 AS INT)
```

En el caso de **MySQL**, la función de búsqueda es `LOCATE`, y `SUBSTRING` debe empezar con 1.
Así que puedes probar con la siguiente `SQL`:

```
Select DATA.*  from 
(
select c.id, RTRIM(SUBSTRING(c.size, 1, LOCATE('-', c.size)-1)) SIZE1 from company c 
) DATA
ORDER BY CAST(DATA.SIZE1 AS INT)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Germán! Entiendo lo que dices, pero lo estoy haciendo desde Intellij y no acabo de ver la sintaxis. Entiendo que el código que comentas debería de ir en:
@Query("select c from company c order by c.size")
    List<Company> findByOrderBySizeAsc();

Comment: Si, las modificaciones sobre la consulta SQL deben ir en la llamada, pero para ajustar la sintaxis hay que saber qué motor de Base de Datos estás utilizando.

Comment: Estoy utilizando mySQL Workbench

Comment: Amplío mi respuesta, para MySQL que varía un poco.

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, puntúala para que a otros usuarios les pueda ser útil.

Comment: Hola Germán, tu respuesta era correcta pero añado lo que tuve que hacer en otro comentario. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Al final tuve que realizar un comparator. El código ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
    public List<Company> findByOrderBySizeAsc() {

    Comparator<Company> bySize =
            (Company c1, Company c2)->
            {
                String sizeC1 = c1.getSize();
                String sizeC2 = c2.getSize();
                String maxSizeC1 = sizeC1.split("[-]|[+]")[0];
                Integer intMaxSizeC1 = Integer.parseInt(maxSizeC1);
                String maxSizeC2 = sizeC2.split("[-]|[+]")[0];
                Integer intMaxSizeC2 = Integer.parseInt(maxSizeC2);
                return intMaxSizeC1.compareTo(intMaxSizeC2);
            };

    List<Company> companyList = companyRepository.findAll().stream().sorted(bySize).toList();

    return companyList;
```